# CSS. Элементы по классу кроме последнего

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Подскажите почему `bobik:not(:last-of-type)` 'не работает' когда после div-а с классом бобик есть div без класса. Я же в CSS делаю выборку по классу, а не по div-ам

Как сделать чтобы стили применялись ко всем блокам с классом бобик, кроме последнего блока с этим классом. БЕЗ ВВОДА ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫХ КЛАССОВ

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="bobik">1 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
  <div class="bobik">2 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
  <div class="bobik">3 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
  <div>4 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
  <p>5 --- 'P' WITHOUT ANY CLASS</p>
  <div class="bobik">6 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
  <div class="bobik">7 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
  <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
  <div class="bobik">9 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: 20px; 
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  background: #fff; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
div{
  background: silver;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.bobik{
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid gray; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.bobik:not(:last-of-type){
  background: #9ED3E9;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

И так же на фидле есть код

https://jsfiddle.net/L580hefa/1/

Answer (score 3):

В css методы `:last-of-type` и `last-child` работают по отчёту от своего родителя. 
По-этому и берётся всегда именно последний элемент родителя. 
Если Вы хотите указать для конкретного поля, то лучше использовать `:nth-child()`, но он тоже не так хорош, при работе с динамическим количеством полей. 
При работе с динамикой Ваш вариант - это использовать js или jquery.

```css
    .main{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        margin: 20px;
        max-width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    div{
        background: silver;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bobik{
        border-radius: 3px;
        border-top: 1px solid gray;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .bobik:not(:nth-child(9)){
        background: #9ED3E9;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="bobik">1 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">2 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">3 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div>4 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <p>5 --- 'P' WITHOUT ANY CLASS</p>
    <div class="bobik">6 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">7 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <div class="bobik">9 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <p>5 --- 'P' WITHOUT ANY CLASS</p>
    <div>4 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
</div>
```

Пример с jquery(не забыть в `head` добавить библиотеку jquery):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        $(".bobik").last().removeClass(); // удаляем текущий класс последнего элемента. В вашем случае этого будет достаточно
        $(".bobik").last().css({ // добавляем стиль, если хочется поставь новый.
            'border-radius':'3px',
            'border-top':'1px solid gray',
            'border-bottom':'1px solid gray'
        });
    }
```

```css
    .main{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        margin: 20px;
        max-width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    div{
        background: silver;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .bobik{
        background: #9ED3E9;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="bobik">1 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">2 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">3 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div>4 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <p>5 --- 'P' WITHOUT ANY CLASS</p>
    <div class="bobik">6 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div class="bobik">7 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <div class="bobik">9 --- 'DIV' WITH CLASS "bobik"</div>
    <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
    <div>8 --- 'DIV' WITHOUT CLASS</div>
</div>
```